# PrimeFaces: How to block navigation through tabs when required fiels aren't filled

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabs, navigation

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5. Is there a way to block the navigation through tabs when the required fields aren't filled? I'm using validation messages now when field are not filled, but after the message is shown, it's still possible to navigate through the tabs.

Example:

```
    <ui:define name="body">
    <h:form id="mainform">
        <h:inputHidden value="none" validator="#{Handler.valideerRoute}"/>

        <p:wizard widgetVar="wizard" flowListener="#{Handler.onFlowProcess}" showNavBar="false">
            <p:tab id="afnemer" title="Select bla">
                <rav:validationerror/>

                <ui:include src="select-something.xhtml"/>

                <duopanel:buttonPanel>
                    <duo:link url="#{request.contextPath}/index.xhtml" label="Cancel"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Further" type="button" onclick="wizard.next();" />
                </duopanel:buttonPanel>
            </p:tab>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this link http://ovaraksin.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/how-to-prevent-tab-changing-in.html

Comment: Thank you, that's indeed what I was looking for. Except i'm using Java and not JavaScript

Comment: Uhmmm you are using PrimeFaces... That contains a lot of javascript. Don't see the problem there